# Filling an area with a pattern saved in a file

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code, how can I fill this closed area with a pattern saved in an outside file as the enclosed one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\node [thin, black] at (0,0) (i){x};
\draw [very thick, blue] (i.center) node (ii){} to [out=5, in=170] ++(0.:7.cm) -- +(-90:2.2cm)  to [out=130, in=-170, looseness=.6] (ii.center) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer loading the `graphicx` package, I use an example image available with this package.

I use the `path picture` option which is defined in the section **Generalized Filling: Using Arbitrary Pictures to Fill a Path** of the TikZ manual.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\node [thin, black] at (0,0) (i){};
\draw [very thick, blue] (i.center) node (ii){} to [out=5, in=170] ++(0.:7.cm) -- +(-90:2.2cm)  to [out=130, in=-170, looseness=.6] (ii.center) -- cycle
[path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics{example-image}};}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

#### Image size

As @zarko rightly points out, it is necessary that the image is larger than the path. Otherwise, there is a hole.

A solution is then to use a magnification factor, here `scale=1.4`.

[image: image size]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe,tikz}

\begin{document}

\Huge{SCALE=1}
\smallskip

\newcommand{\facteur}{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [thin, black] at (0,0) (i){};
\node[] at (i.center){\includegraphics[scale=\facteur]{example-image}};
\draw [very thick, blue,fill=cyan!80,fill opacity=.5] (-2.7,1) node (ii){} to [out=5, in=170] ++(0.:7.cm) -- +(-90:2.2cm)  to [out=130, in=-170, looseness=.6] (ii.center) -- cycle
[path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[scale=\facteur]{example-image}};}];

\draw(current bounding box.south east)rectangle(current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}


\bigskip
\Huge{SCALE=1}
\smallskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [thin, black] at (0,0) (i){};
\node[] at (i.center){\includegraphics[scale=\facteur]{example-image-duck}};
\draw [very thick, blue,fill=cyan!80,fill opacity=.5] (-2.7,1) node (ii){} to [out=5, in=170] ++(0.:7.cm) -- +(-90:2.2cm)  to [out=130, in=-170, looseness=.6] (ii.center) -- cycle
[path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[scale=\facteur]{example-image-duck}};}];

\draw(current bounding box.south east)rectangle(current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\renewcommand{\facteur}{1.4}
\bigskip
\Huge{SCALE=1.4}
\smallskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [thin, black] at (0,0) (i){};
\node[] at (i.center){\includegraphics[scale=\facteur]{example-image-duck}};
\draw [very thick, blue,fill=cyan!80,fill opacity=.5] (-2.7,1) node (ii){} to [out=5, in=170] ++(0.:7.cm) -- +(-90:2.2cm)  to [out=130, in=-170, looseness=.6] (ii.center) -- cycle
[path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[scale=\facteur]{example-image-duck}};}];

\draw(current bounding box.south east)rectangle(current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1), however if I replace `example-image` with `example-image-duck` result is not satisfactory (natural image size seems to be too small).

Comment: If the image size is smaller than the path, is there a way to make it repeated to fill the whole path!

Comment: How can I upload the file containing the pattern?

Comment: The graphicx package allows you to enlarge or deform it by enlarging it horizontally or vertically. It does not require paving. Ask a new question for this new problem.

Comment: (i) to me is simpler to prescribe pattern image width (ii) the OP path construction contain clutter, it can be write shorter, for example as: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (i);
\path[preaction={draw=blue!50, ultra thick},clip]
    (i) to [out= 15, in=165] ++(0:7.cm) -- +(-90:2.4cm)
        to [out=130, in=195, looseness=.4] (i);
\node [minimum width=\linewidth, minimum height=0.5\linewidth,
           right=-5mm of i]
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Hany What pattern are you talking about? About the question about image repetition, the graphicx package allows you to enlarge or deform it by enlarging it horizontally or vertically. It does not require paving. Ask a new question for this new problem.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

Since i haven't your pattern file  I use `example-image-duck` defined in the `graphicx` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\coordinate (i);
\path[preaction={draw=blue!50, ultra thick},clip] 
    (i) to [out=5, in=170] ++(0.:7.cm) -- +(-90:2.2cm)  
        to [out=130, in=-170, looseness=.6] (i);
\node (j) [minimum width=\linewidth, minimum height=0.5\linewidth, 
           right=-5mm of i] 
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry for the delay, I was very busy.